# Passing variables with Apollo useMutation hook

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo

I am using the `useMutation` hook to submit form data in my app.  I need to pass data not known at the first render of the component, so I am trying to use the function returned from the `useMutation` hook to pass a complex object.  I am following the example in the Apollo docs (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/) but I am getting a 400 Network Error, which I believe is related to my variable not passed correctly.  When I hard code the data in the mutation, it works.

**component.js**

```
const [sendLineItems, { loading, data, error }] = useMutation(CANCEL_LINE_ITEM);

export const structureCancelLineInput = (data) => {
  return {
    request: {
      requestId: '1234',
      orderLines: Object.values(data).map(line => ({
        cancelRequestQuantity: line.quantity,
        reasonCode: line.reason.code,
        reasonText: line.reason.text,
      }))
    }
  }
};

const handleSubmit = () => {
  const request = structureCancelLineInput(selectedLines);
  sendLineItems({ variables: request });
};
```

(selectedLines is coming from React Context here, updated from the form in the component)

**mutation.js**

```
const CANCEL_LINE_ITEM = gql`
  mutation CancelLineItemMutation($request: CancelLineItemInputV1!) {
    cancelLineItem(input: $request) {
      id
      eta
      status
    }
  }
`;
```

**schema**

```
input CancelLineItemInputV1 {
    request: cancelLineItemRequest!
}

input cancelLineItemRequest {
    requestId: String,
    orderLines: [cancel_orderLines]
}

input cancel_orderLines {
    cancelRequestQuantity: Int!,
    reasonCode: String!,
    reasonText: String!,
}
```

Is there a syntax or object structuring error I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**

If I look at the initial error object, I get the following message:

```
"Variable \"$request\" of required type \"CSOrderModsV1_CancelLineItemInputV1!\" was not provided."
```

I could be wrong, but I believe the error is coming from my trying to pass a custom object type, since it does work when its just expecting a string.  I cannot find an example of someone passing a custom object on the frontend, and I'm not sure how a POJO (not using TypeScript) would become typed, especially a custom type defined on the backend.  Nor do I know how to pass the data without a custom object.

Comment: Inspect the `error` object returned by the hook, or look at the actual response from the server in dev tools. The `errors` array returned by the server will include details about what is wrong with your request.

Comment: @DanielRearden, that's helpful thanks!  I'm getting : "Variable \"$request\" of required type \"CSOrderModsV1_CancelLineItemInputV1!\" was not provided."

Comment: So the error indicates the variable `request` is not being provided at all. Look at how you're passing it in. What is the `variables` parameter supposed to look like?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe the error is coming from my trying to pass a custom object type, since it does work when its just expecting a string.  I cannot find an example of someone passing a custom object on the frontend, and I'm not sure how a POJO would become typed in that way, nor do I know how to pass a custom object that contains a nested custom object as anything else.

Comment: There's a difference between sending `{variables: request}` and `{variables: {request}}`

Answer (score -1):

Do this. It should work. If you notice in the graphql query it takes `input` as argument so `input` should be mentioned inside `variable` object.

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {
  const request = structureCancelLineInput(selectedLines);
   sendLineItems({ variables: {input: request}});
 };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to change anything.  It just renames the variable on the other end

Comment: Try to console.log the request variable and see how it's structure looks like

Comment: Also under Dev tools check  network tab headers. You should be able to see if you're passing any variable to that mutation